Не могу понять почему не работает import
(venv) damir@damir-WARD-H202:~/Desktop/electronics-shop-project-main$ python3 homework-1/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/damir/Desktop/electronics-shop-project-main/homework-1/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.item import Item
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

├── homework-1
│   ├── main.py
│   └── README.md
├── homework-2
│   ├── main.py
│   └── README.md
├── homework-3
│   ├── main.py
│   └── README.md
├── homework-4
│   ├── main.py
│   └── README.md
├── homework-5
│   ├── main.py
│   └── README.md
├── homework-6
│   ├── main.py
│   └── README.md
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── item.py
│   └── items.csv
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_item.py


Т.к. у вас там есть pyproject.toml, то теоретически можно установить ваш пакет через pip командой pip install -e . (точка должна быть в команде - это означает что текущая папка устанавливается как пакет). Тогда редактирование PYTHONPATH не нужно будет.

Решил таким путем:
$ export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
